# SharePoint page layout cannot find SPWebPartManager

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Feature with a Page Layout containing Webpartzones, however when I try to activate the Feature, SharePoint gives an error saying the URL is invalid.  Apparently the layout is not able to access SPWebPartManager placed in default.master.  When I put SPWebPartManager in the layout, it works fine. I tried using a custom Master page, still it gives this error.  What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the references you use for the master page.  I don't have your code but I remember having to work with ../../_catalogs/ or ../_catalogs/ and possibly even /_catalogs/ as it all depends upon the location of your page.

Comment: I'm using "~masterurl/default.master" to refer to the master page.

Comment: What I am getting at is "did you try different paths instead of ~/masterurl?

Good luck!